# How to solve $ u'(t)=(u(t))^2-5u(t)+6 $ rigorously?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following homework question:

Show that the Cauchy problem:
$$
u'(t)=(u(t))^2-5u(t)+6
$$
for $t\in[0,\infty[$ and with $u(0)=u_0$ has a global solution for $u_0≤3$ and a maximal, non-global solution for $u_0>3$.

In the solution, they proceed as follows:
$$
\frac{du(t)}{dt}=(u(t))^2-5u(t)+6\implies \frac{du(t)}{(u(t))^2-5u(t)+6}=dt \implies \int \frac{du(t)}{(u(t))^2-5u(t)+6}=\int dt \implies \log\left(\frac{u(t)-3}{u(t)-2}\right)=t+C
$$
And they deduce the solutions for $u$ from there.

I'm a bit surprised by this approach, because as I'm studying maths (and not physics) this seems a bit vague… Why can we divide by $(u(t))^2-5u(t)+6$ even though it could be $0$? How to obtain the constant solutions $u\equiv 2$ and $u\equiv 3$ because they don't seem to be covered by this approach?

If somebody could provide an approach without this kind of uncertainty, i would be very grateful.

Comment: For the DEQ, [*Separation of Variables*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables). For the integral,  [*Partial Fractions*](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/PartialFractions.aspx) as it factors as $(u-3) (u-2)$.

Comment: I think you are talking about domains of validity of the solution (this depends on the initial conditions). I also appreciate the knock on physicists  (where is the nearest Chemist to make my physicist self feel better!!)

Comment: The two singular solutions $u=2$ and $u=3$ can be seen by a simple inspection of the equation, than, when we divide by $u^2-5u+6$ we take $u \ne 2$ and $u\ne 3$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The constant solution $u\equiv 2$ is the unique solution to the Cauchy problem for $t_0\in \mathbb{R}$, 
$$ \begin{cases} \frac{du}{dt}=(u(t))^2-5u(t)+ 6, \\ u(t_0)=2.\end{cases}$$
Consequently (by Cauchy-Lipschitz theorem), a solution of $\frac{du}{dt}=(u(t))^2-5u(t)+ 6$ is either always equal to $2$ or never equal to $2$.

The same holds for the constant solution $u\equiv 3$. So by continuity, a solution $u$ of your equation is such that, for all $t$, $u(t)$ belongs to $]-\infty,2)$ or to $\{ 2 \}$, or to $(2,3)$, or to $\{ 3 \}$ or to $(3,+\infty[$. Now that you know this, the integration can be done easily in the region $]-\infty,2)$ (or $(2,3)$ ; $(3,+\infty[$).

Remark: this phenomenon is due to the fact that if $t\mapsto u(t)$ is a solution of your equation, then, for a fixed parameter $\tau$, $t\mapsto u(t+\tau)$ is also a solution of the equation.

Comment: Thank you very much; I formalized your argument and got a truthfully satisfying proof :)

Comment: Great answer! I just don't understand the last sentence. Can I dare ask you explain it for the thick-headed that I am? Shouldn't we have restrictions on the fixed parameter $τ$ so $t$ will stay in the domain of the function $u$. Also I don't see why the remark infers what is above, Thank you in advance.

Comment: @John11 Please look at [this wikipage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_system_%28mathematics%29).

Comment: @user37238 Awesome! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

$$u'=u^2-5u+6$$
This is a Riccati ODE. So, change of function : $\quad u(t)= -\frac{y'(t)}{y(t)}$

$u'=-\frac{y''}{y}+\frac{y'^2}{y^2} = \left(-\frac{y'(t)}{y(t)} \right)^2 -5\left(-\frac{y'(t)}{y(t)} \right)+6$

$$y'' + 5 y' +6 y = 0$$

$$y=c_1e^{-3t}+c_2e^{-2t}$$

$$u(t)=-\frac{y'}{y}=\frac{3c_1e^{-3t}+2c_2e^{-2t}}{c_1e^{-3t}+c_2e^{-2t}}$$

$$u(t)=\frac{3C+2e^{t}}{C+e^{t}}$$